# How to solve .js.map throws error in console. after added the map file

Tags: angular, webpack

Below error message getting after i added the corresponding map file

```
scripts.bundle.js:118 [Script Loader] SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:130)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../../src/assets/js/showdown.js.map (scripts.bundle.js:187)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.3 (scripts.bundle.js:264)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (inline.bundle.js:26)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
log @ scripts.bundle.js:118
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with webpack that isn't typical?

Comment: @ShellNinja not done anything on webpack